# Can't connect to any networks with an Intel Wireless-N 2230 or ASUS USB Dongle

Tags: wireless, 15.04, iwlwifi

I am currently running Ubuntu 15.05.

> **Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230:**

I have a MSI mobo with Intel Wifi:

```
~ % lspci | grep Centrino
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

But it doesn't work in Ubuntu (works in Antergos Live USB). I can't connect to any networks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVwZO.png

I tried `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0/1/8`, doesn't do anything.

`syslog` output:

```
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.001342] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002851] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002853] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002854] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002856] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002858] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002859] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002860] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002861] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002862] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002864] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.002865] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.004371] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.004373] Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.004448] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.004774] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.014285] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.014288] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.014288] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.014290] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.014335] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.030334] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> rfkill4: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill4) (driver iwlwifi)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill4...
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill4.
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.033525] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan2: renamed from wlan0
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/net/wlan2, iface: wlan2)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/net/wlan2, iface: wlan2): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'iwlwifi' ifindex: 7)
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started ifup for wlan2.
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting ifup for wlan2...
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu sh[6636]: Unknown interface wlan2
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.053183] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.060618] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.307410] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu kernel: [10066.314843] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): preparing device
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1261]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1261]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <warn> could not get interface properties: No readable properties in this interface.
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Sep 13 17:17:04 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <warn> could not get interface properties: No readable properties in this interface.
Sep 13 17:17:06 ubuntu ModemManager[1044]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Sep 13 17:17:14 ubuntu NetworkManager[1054]: <info> (wlan2): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
```

`dmesg` output:

```
[10066.004371] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
[10066.004373] Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation
[10066.004448] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[10066.004774] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[10066.014285] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[10066.014288] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[10066.014288] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[10066.014290] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[10066.014335] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[10066.030334] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[10066.033525] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan2: renamed from wlan0
[10066.053183] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[10066.060618] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[10066.307410] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[10066.314843] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[10394.219408] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[10394.220801] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[10394.220803] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[10394.220803] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[10394.220805] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10394.220806] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10394.220806] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10394.220808] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10394.220809] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[10394.220809] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[10394.220810] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10394.220811] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
```

> **ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N13 802.11n Network Adapter:**

So I bought a fancy ASUS n-13 USB dongle that advertises Linux support (was $40). Its from 2012, so I figured it should work with 2015 Ubuntu.

```
~ % lsusb | grep ASUS
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0b05:17ab ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N13 802.11n Network Adapter (rev. B1) [Realtek RTL8192CU]
```

But nope. It kind of works for a minute (ping 400+, 0.8mbit speed), and then:

```
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
```

`echo 83886080 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max` didn't help.

UPDATE: Now the Asus USB dongle won't even connect to any networks anymore:

```
ep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu whoopsie[1084]: [11:31:58] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu whoopsie[1084]: [11:31:58] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu whoopsie[1084]: [11:31:58] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu whoopsie[1084]: [11:31:58] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): device state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'user-requested') [100 110 39]
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): device state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested') [110 30 39]
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): deactivating device (reason 'user-requested') [39]
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3956
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::f279:59ff:feec:6350 on wlan1.
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan1.IPv6 with address fe80::f279:59ff:feec:6350.
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Interface wlan1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.33.100 on wlan1.
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan1.IPv4 with address 192.168.33.100.
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.905230] wlan1: deauthenticating from c0:c1:c0:f9:de:a5 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Interface wlan1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1277]: wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:c1:c0:f9:de:a5 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu dnsmasq[1707]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.916289] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918223] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918225] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918226] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918227] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918228] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918229] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918230] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918231] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918232] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918233] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 2115.918233] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1277]: wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -3)
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 13 11:31:59 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -3)
Sep 13 11:32:01 ubuntu ntpdate[4075]: name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Sep 13 11:32:01 ubuntu nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'down' for wlan1
Sep 13 11:32:01 ubuntu nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'up' for wlan1
Sep 13 11:32:01 ubuntu nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'down' for wlan1
Sep 13 11:32:01 ubuntu ntpdate[4279]: name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) starting connection 'SHAW-2F2A49'
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1/wireless): connection 'SHAW-2F2A49' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'SHAW-2F2A49'
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1277]: wlan1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8 (SSID='SHAW-2F2A49' freq=2437 MHz)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.300679] wlan1: authenticate with 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1277]: wlan1: Trying to associate with 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8 (SSID='SHAW-2F2A49' freq=2437 MHz)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.311233] wlan1: send auth to 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8 (try 1/3)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.313599] wlan1: authenticated
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.313680] wlan1: associating with AP with corrupt beacon
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.315163] wlan1: associate with 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8 (try 1/3)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1277]: wlan1: Associated with 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.326506] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.326857] wlan1: associated
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.326900] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328165] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328167] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328168] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328169] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328170] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328171] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328172] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 2118.328173] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1277]: wlan1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1277]: wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 74:85:2a:43:0d:b8 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'SHAW-2F2A49'.
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> dhclient started with pid 4304
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Sep 13 11:32:02 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.170 on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x62dfa69a)
Sep 13 11:32:04 ubuntu whoopsie[1084]: [11:32:04] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Sep 13 11:32:04 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan1.IPv6 with address fe80::f279:59ff:feec:6350.
Sep 13 11:32:04 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: New relevant interface wlan1.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep 13 11:32:04 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1064]: Registering new address record for fe80::f279:59ff:feec:6350 on wlan1.*.
Sep 13 11:32:06 ubuntu ntpdate[4329]: name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Sep 13 11:32:11 ubuntu dhclient: message repeated 2 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.170 on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x62dfa69a)]
Sep 13 11:32:17 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xac99d135)
Sep 13 11:32:20 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xac99d135)
Sep 13 11:32:28 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xac99d135)
Sep 13 11:32:43 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xac99d135)
Sep 13 11:32:47 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <warn> (wlan1): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Sep 13 11:32:47 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> (wlan1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 4304
Sep 13 11:32:47 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Sep 13 11:32:47 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Sep 13 11:32:47 ubuntu NetworkManager[1079]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

If anyone knows how to solve any of these issues, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try 14.04.3 LTS?

Comment: @Daniel I cannot do that. I need this setup to work, I can't reinstall.

Comment: Do `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've tried, no luck :(

Comment: I don't have a detailed answer for you but I do have a few suggestions.  First make sure your computer is set to the correct region.  Wireless channels vary by country so having the wrong country set can make it so you can't connect to some routers.

Comment: @WalterJ89 I checked the Region/Time settings and I tried changing channels in router admin panel, without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through your log file, I find myself seeing two possibilities.

1) The router isn't assigning an IP address to Ubuntu. I've experienced this before where it works with one distro and not another -- same machine. Ended up assigning a static IP which solved the issue.

or

2) As someone else points out above, have you tried a **live distro** release of 14.04.3 LTS? If this works (older kernel) and Antergos is working (super-new kernel), then I suspect the issue could be your kernel. Again, not suggesting a re-install, I'm pointing out that you may need to narrow down cause. This is how we do that.

My gut tells me this is almost definitely 15.04 just being the buggy release it is. Test out the 14.04.3 LTS -- just for testing.

If it fails, my money is on you need a newer kernel due to support.

If it works, then my money is on the 15.04 release's kernel having a bug. Solution is to roll forward or backwards with another kernel.

If none of these are working, I go back to my point about your assigned IP address. My two cents.

Comment: Thank you very much for for your help.

I have tried booting into 14.04.3, and I have had no luck with getting either device to work.

I do not know how would one make an static IP, I will google it and report on progress. 

Thanks

Comment: Assigning static IP in router + configuring via NetworkManager enabled me to use USB Wifi stick. Lets hope it works for more than few hours this time.